# How do I deploy custom web part to Sharepoint Online Site Collection?

Tags: web-part, deployment, sandbox-solution

After uploading the wsp to the site collection using the browser and activating it, everything seems to work fine and i see all the page layouts, masterpage, content types, lists and webparts. BUT, when I try to add a web part to a web part zone, i get the following error. "Sandboxed code execution request failed" Any suggestions would be helpful. 
Here is the code in the web part file AnnouncementsWP.cs (its not a visual webpart)

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace SANDBOXEDSOLUTION.Custom_Web_Parts.AnnouncementsWP
{
    [ToolboxItemAttribute(false)]
    public class AnnouncementsWP : System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart
    {
        [WebBrowsable(true), Personalizable(true), WebDisplayName("Announcements List")]
        public string _announcementList { get; set; }

        private String annoucementList = "Announcements";

        protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {
            annoucementList = _announcementList;
        }

        protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {
            base.Render(writer);

            try
            {
                string announcementslist = "";
                SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;

                        try
                        {
                            if (web.Lists[annoucementList] != null)
                            {
                                SPList List = web.Lists[annoucementList];

                                announcementslist += "<div class='carousel g1'><div class='buttons'></div><div class='holder'><ul class='carousel-list'>";
                                foreach (SPListItem li in List.Items)
                                {
                                    DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(li.GetFormattedValue("AnnouncementDate"));
                                    announcementslist += "<li><em class='date'><span>";
                                    announcementslist += date.ToString("MMMM") + " " + date.ToString("dd") + ", " + date.ToString("yyyy");
                                    announcementslist += "</span></em><div class='text'><h2>";
                                    announcementslist += li.GetFormattedValue("Title");
                                    announcementslist += "</h2><p>";
                                    announcementslist += li.GetFormattedValue("Announcement");
                                    announcementslist += "</p></div></li>";
                                }
                                announcementslist += "</ul></div></div>";
                            }
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            announcementslist += "An error has occured in this web part.";
                        }

                writer.Write(announcementslist);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                writer.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try it in a local sandbox environment?

Comment: This might be a dumb question but did you activate the solution in the solution gallery?

Comment: Yes, I deployed it to a local sandbox environment and it worked. But this was not sharepoint online, this was sharepoint 2010.

Comment: Yes, everything is activated. I ended up using out of the box webparts cause I couldn't figure out how to deploy custom ones.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that this call will give u an exception if the list doesn't exist: `web.Lists[annoucementList]`

Instead do `web.Lists.TryGetList("NameOfList");` That one will give u a proper `null` if the list is not there, the first method will actually crash.

Also if `GetFormattedValue` returns null, for instance to create your `DateTime` date, this will probably also crash: `date.ToString("MMMM")`

If none of this works try to write some debug info and use a `Controls.Add(new LiteralControl{ Text = "somedebugtext" });` to print out some debug info. Unfortunately the only way to get some decent debug info.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check these solutions? -

http://bramnuyts.wordpress.com/2011/05/17/sandboxed-code-execution-request-failed/

http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/p/3977/15749.aspx

If these don't work then, there may be something in the code that is being blocked from running by SharePoint.